# SEO, should I manipulate the URI showed in my website for SEO purposes?

Tags: filter, seo, uri

I am designing a website that, just like [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com), has many filters for the front page such as 'new', 'top', 'historic', 'active'...

If you were to click on the filter 'new', our url would change from

```
www.mywebsite.com/main/
```

to

```
www.mywebsite.com/main/new
```

and the data displayed would change it's order in order to show the "newest" content.

However, I have heard that for SEO purposes, the more links you have pointing to your website the better, I thought it could be a good idea to keep the URI the same way even after you click on a filter, so you would click on 'new' and the URI would still show

```
www.mywebsite.com/main/
```

Doing this, if 4 people share my website, it will be better shown on google right?
Because google will see this (even if they copy paste the URI while viewing a filter) and all 4 links are the same.

```
www.mywebsite.com/main/
www.mywebsite.com/main/
www.mywebsite.com/main/
www.mywebsite.com/main/
```

While if I don't do this people may share the 4 links like this

```
www.mywebsite.com/main/new
www.mywebsite.com/main/active
www.mywebsite.com/main/top
www.mywebsite.com/main/
```

and Google would think of them as different links thus giving less 'reputation' to my main page and spreading it through the different filters.

Comment: Google does not reveal how they rank the pages. However, I don't think it really matters how many links there are to an individual page, but instead how many links there are to your whole site. That is assuming you do have links between the pages in your site.

Comment: Further, if you have the same url for multiple pages, that would be bad for the user since the user could not bookmark the individual pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can add a canonical link to the page (1) in the metatags, and (2) yes, the same page should have only one link, otherwise it would seem like duplicate content, which at the current time Google doesn't like.

Answer (score 2):

Use canonical tags to avoid duplicate content penalty, but still use different URLs for new/top/etc this way you will still get good result in Google's SERP and the links will also be useful to the users.